# What are these aircraft? Seen in silhouette over Palm Springs

Tags: propeller, aircraft-identification

[image: screen capture - details of original image unknown]

Screen capture on iMac, of photo posted and claimed taken 11/21/15.
Palm Springs, CA

Comment: DC-3 x 2, a.k.a. C-47.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like two Douglas DC-3, the one on the right being the military version known as the C-47 "Skytrain".

[image: pic]

<sup>[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_C-47_Skytrain#/media/File:Douglas_c47-a_skytrain_n1944a_cotswoldairshow_2010_arp.jpg): Adrian Pingstone</sup>

Comment: Also to add, the C-47 in the picture in the question and the one above have the European theatre paint.

Comment: Gotta love the ol' Gooney Bird ;) one of the earliest airliners to still be in commercial service...if not *the* earliest.

Comment: @SMSvonderTann, the black and white stripes were added specifically for the invasion in Normandy (to reduce risk of friendly fire as aircraft of many different types, paint schemes and insignia were involved).

Comment: What I found interesting was that the roundel bars don't have any red on them. The red,white and blue bars on the roundel didn't come in until 1947. Originally it was just a star in a circle with no bars; the bars were added because a different shape made them easier to identify.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_military_aircraft_national_insignia